# iOS 4.3 Inline MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am using MPMoviePlayerController in my UIView and the goal is to put it there on View as inline view. The problem is that the code doesn't work except the full screen.

```
-(IBAction)startVideo {
    //start video here
    NSURL *path = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[self localVideoPath:NO]];

    // Create custom movie player   
    MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer = [[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:path] autorelease];

    [moviePlayer setScalingMode:MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill];
    [moviePlayer setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleNone];
    [moviePlayer setFullscreen:FALSE];

    // May help to reduce latency
    [moviePlayer prepareToPlay];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
        addObserver:self
        selector:@selector(onMSAASDone:)
        name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
        object:moviePlayer];


    //---play partial screen---
    //moviePlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 300);
    moviePlayer.view.frame = image.frame;
    //[[moviePlayer view] setFrame: [image bounds]];

    [image removeFromSuperview];

    [self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];

    // Show the movie player as modal
    //[self presentModalViewController:moviePlayer animated:YES];

    // Prep and play the movie
    [moviePlayer play]; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sample code from Apple is flawed or let's say outdated. You need to add the **moviePlayer's view** as subview to your view. Something like this:

```
MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer = [[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:path] autorelease];
...
// Adjust positioning where I used the bound of the outer view (of type UIView)
moviePlayer.view.frame = outerView.bounds;
// Now add the movie player to the outer view
[outerView addSubView:moviePlayer.view];
...
```

This should do the trick.

Sorry, I did not see that you added the subview already.

Okay, for a sample code you can take the XCode sample project called **MoviePlayer_iPhone** (inside the XCode documentation for MPMoviePlayerController you'll find a link for the **MoviePlayer** sample project) and just adjust **AppDelegate's initAndPlayMovie** this way:

```
-(void)initAndPlayMovie:(NSURL *)movieURL
{
    // Initialize a movie player object with the specified URL
    MPMoviePlayerController *mp = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];
    if (mp)
    {
        // save the movie player object
        self.moviePlayer = mp;
        [mp release];

        // Apply the user specified settings to the movie player object
        [self setMoviePlayerUserSettings];

        self.moviePlayer.view.frame = self.window.bounds;            
        [self.window addSubview:self.moviePlayer.view];

        // Play the movie!
        [self.moviePlayer play];
    }
}
```

This one is crude because it does not set the frame or centers the view but it should display the movie when you go to **local** and click on **Play Movie**.

The only drawback I saw was that the fullscreen is not going black. That said the sample project is pretty weird and not very well written. That said it displays the non-fullscreen video.

Comment: Can you create a simple project where you are adding MPMoviePlayerController inside view as inline and it plays video from  resources? That would be really helpful to see how you are doing this. Because I have tried every way around and it just isn't working.

Comment: You Know I think the frame and position part is more crucial here. Can you re-write it to use the frame or bounds?

Comment: Also here setMoviePlayerUserSettings is missing.

Comment: Get the MoviePlayer sample project from XCode. BTW you can ommit this line as far as I saw.

Comment: Are you sure there is a way to play video in the portion of a View and not the fullscreen?

Comment: I got it fixed. I had many mistakes there. May I post my own answer or what?